# Change the first index of each sublist in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

Change the first index of each sublist in a list. from 1,2 , 3 ...
for example -

```
data = [['45', 'gh', 'tg'], ['23', 'gf', 'gzs'], ['21', 'xzs', 'gd']]
```

I want to get

```
data = [[1, 'gh', 'tg'], [2, 'gf', 'gzs'], [3, 'xzs', 'gd']]
```

which means changing the first index of each sublist.
I tried

```
for subs in data:
i = 0
subs[0] = i + 1
```

Can some one help me to build this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do in your attempt. `subs[0] = i + 0` just after declaring `i = 0`?

Comment: something + 0 = the same something.

Comment: Sorry I meant + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension using enumerate to get the index. `i+1` is done to start the index from 1 because the default index starts from 0 in python enumerate.

`enumerate` returns the index and the individual elements of the enumerated list. `j` here will be the list and `j[1]` and `j[2]` will be the first and the second element respectively.

```
new_data = [[i+1, j[1], j[2]] for i, j in enumerate(data)]
# [[1, 'gh', 'tg'], [2, 'gf', 'gzs'], [3, 'xzs', 'gd']]
```

Another similar alternative is following where `j[1:]` refers to the rest of the list from second element until the last excluding the first. You then add the first index to create the final list.

```
new_data = [[i+1] + j[1:] for i, j in enumerate(data)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is simple code that you may be find as useful:

```
data = [['45', 'gh', 'tg'], ['23', 'gf', 'gzs'], ['21', 'xzs', 'gd']]


for i in range (len(data)):

     data[i][0] = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Bazingaa's answer is probably the ideal solution, but here's another SUPER inefficient way using `map`. (I just think it's important to know about other solutions when solving a problem.)

```
list(map(lambda sublist: [data.index(sublist) + 1] + sublist[1:], data))
# => [[1, 'gh', 'tg'], [2, 'gf', 'gzs'], [3, 'xzs', 'gd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `enumerate` to iterate the list You can pass an argument to enumerate to start the numbering from in your case it should start from `1`

```
[[idx,lis[1],lis[2]] for idx,lis in enumerate(data,1)]
```

Comment: The OP wants the index to be integer. Please see the desired output posted in the question. It is `1`, `2` and so on instead of `'1'`, `'2'`...

Answer (score 0):

I find this more readable,

```
for index,l in enumerate(data):
    data[index][0] = index+1

print(data)

# output
[[1, 'gh', 'tg'], [2, 'gf', 'gzs'], [3, 'xzs', 'gd']]
```